# Iterated Tangent Category Construction

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ct.category-theory

We can think of the "tangent category" of a category $\mathcal{C}$ at an object $A$ as being the abelian group objects in the overcategory $\mathcal{C}/A$ (with whatever conditions I need on $\mathcal{C}$ for this to make sense).  In the case that $\mathcal{C}$ is commutative rings, I can think of this as being the category of square zero extensions of $A$, or equivalently, $A$-modules. Suppose I were to iterate this process.  Can I think of iterations as being like higher level "approximations" (i.e. quadratic category, cubic category)? If I iterate it a countable number of times, do I obtain some sort of formal object?

One obvious initial issue with my question is to determine what one means by iterate.  I imagine it might make sense to take the tangent category AGAIN at the point $A$, which corresponds to the square zero extension $A[x]/x^2$. At the first level, this obtains all $A$-modules. Also, everything in the category of $A$-modules is already an abelian group, so what do I want to mean by taking abelian group objects over $A$ (as the square-zero extension of itself)?  Is it the case that not all $A$-modules are in fact abelian group objects in the overcategory over some particular module?

thanks!